# Can I achieve auto-sizing in Less file?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I have this class:

```
.tab-content a.button {
  .round-borders(0px);
}

.tab-content a.button:first-child {
  .round-borders-only-left();
}
.tab-content a.button:last-child {
  .round-borders-only-right();
}
```

What I want to achieve. It there are two elements, they should fit row with same size, hence be extended with `.col-md-6`

If there are 3 of them, with `.col-md-4`, if there are 4 of them, then `.col-md-4`, and further with 12/ count of tab-content children, rounded to min (12/5 => 2).

**EDIT**

```
<div class="tab-content">
<a class="button col-md-12" href="/programs/12/streams/new">Добавить поток</a><a class="button col-md-12" href="/programs/12/courses/new">Добавить курс</a>
</div>
```

For example, I have this `div.tab-content` with two `a.button`children. Now I need to manually apply `col-md-12` (I use 24 columns grid system) to each element to have them both same size && fill the parent div.

Is there any way for this to define it in less and this to be auto-applied, taken it may be 2,3,4 and more ot them autogenerated (as part of rails view template code)?

Can it be done in less file and can you show an example?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. Do you have any html to help clarify?

Comment: In `css` you can use `.class + .class { // Apply some style here }`, so maybe that could work in `less` too.

Comment: @ViperCode, i edited to clarify

Comment: Oh ok, I think I understand, you want to automatically apply col-md-XX
to your code and always make them the same width and fill the parent?

Comment: @ViperCode, exactly. I wondered is it achievable without plain javascript, through css.less

Comment: Looked into it more. I don't see a way for `less` to apply an existing class to your elements like that. It will generate a `.css` file that has styles for those elements defined, but actually applying `.col-md-*` to a class seems beyond that capability. Javascript would be able to do this no problem though, looping over and applying the corresponding `col-md-*` dependent on the count of the elements.

Comment: Exactly, this would have to be done at the DOM level, either through javascript or PHP